# Changing the order of an item in a list using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, material-ui

I have created a list using material UI and reactjs, and when a new element is added to the list the new element will go on top of the list. 
I have a requirement where when I click on an element on the list the element should be strike-through and that now that element should be listed on the bottom of the list.
I was able to strike-through the element when clicked, but I am confused as to how to bring the element to the bottom of the list

How should I approach this problem?

The code of the listlayout.js is presented here, In this code, the added items are listed, and I need to find the way to change the list order when an element is stricked

app.js

```
    class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            items:[],
            newItem:{
                id:'',
                itemText:''
            },
            updateItem:false
        };
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }

handleInput = e =>{
        this.setState({
            newItem:{
                id:1 + Math.random(),
                itemText: e.target.value

            }
        });

};

    addItem = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
         const typedItem = this.state.newItem;

        if(typedItem.itemText !==""){
            const typedItems=[...this.state.items,typedItem];
            this.setState({
                items:typedItems,
                newItem:{
                    id:'',
                    itemText: ''
                },
                updateItem:false
            })
        }
    };




    render() {
        return (
            <div >

                <HeaderBar/>


                             <ListLayout items={this.state.items}

                                        />


            </div>



        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

ListLayout.js

```js
const ToDoList = props => {
  const clearList = props.clearList;
  const deleteItem = props.deleteItem;
  const updateItem = props.updateItem;
  const strikeList = props.strikeList;

  const listItems = item => {
    return <div key={item.id}>{item.itemText}</div>;
  };

  const completed = id => {
    document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    return true;
  };

  const strikeTextMethod = id => {
    completed(id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container justify="center" alignContent="center">
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            To do List
          </Typography>

          <div className={classes.demo}>
            <List dense={dense}>
              {items
                .slice(0)
                .reverse()
                .map(x => (
                  <ListItem
                    key={x.id}
                    button
                    id={x.id}
                    onClick={() => strikeTextMethod(x.id)}
                    divider
                  >
                    <ListItemText primary={listItems(x)} />
                    <ListItemSecondaryAction></ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToDoList;
```

Comment: Welcome @thumalee, could you please share your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: You can sort the array after strike-through

Comment: I have added the code, that I think I needed to be changed is there any more codes that you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mainatain the `strike` event for each item in the array. You can add an additional property to the array items, like `isStriked` or `status`.. something like that.

Then you can sort them accordingly..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210298/discussion-on-answer-by-barun-patro-changing-the-order-of-an-item-in-a-list-usin).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be the entire solution. I don't see the definition of items as an example.

but something like this could be a workaround.

```
     const ToDoList = props => {

        const [items, setItems] = React.useState(props.items || []); // Initial values

        // Maybe you need to these lines to sync the items state.
        React.useEffect(
            () => {
                setItems(items)
            },
            [props.items]
        )

      const completed = id => {
        document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        return true;
      };



      const strikeTextMethod = id => {
        const index = items.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
        const newItems = [items[index], ...items.slice(0, index - 1), ...items.slice(index + 1)]
        setItems(newItems);
        completed(id);
      };
      return (

     )

}
```

Comment: I have added my full code, I am bit unable to understand this code , could you please explain it more

Comment: Changing the order a list means another state of your application. You should build another array with the desired order and change the state. I just created a newState called `items` and change the order of it. (you can forget about the `useEffect` for simplicity)

Comment: so I need to add another array in my app.js where I initialize the state?

Comment: I don't think so. I updated my answer. just add the codes to your solution. I changed this line: `const [items, setItems] = React.useState(props.items || []);`

Comment: I did but then when I click to add the item the item does not get added to the list